# SQL - Create table for store weight and height

Tags: mysql

I am looking on internet for 3 hours, but i dont find any solution.
I would like to create an SQL database via script. I storing user weight and height in a table, but i do not know which is the best type for it.

> SQL code

```
CREATE TABLE details (
  ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id int(11) NOT NULL REFERENCES user(ID),
  weight decimal(5,2) UNSIGNED NULL,
  height tinyint UNSIGNED NULL
);
```

I want store height in cm [100 - 220]
and weight in Kg [30.0 - 150.0] example. weight -> ##.#

**Edit:**
This is MySQL server.

Comment: This looks a lot like mysql but you also tagged this with sql server. Which DBMS are you actually using? What is wrong with what you have?

Comment: which database is it? There's plenty of online datatype descriptions for both MySQL and SQL-Server. You have to decide what works for you - do you want integers only or single precision numbers. We can't tell you what is "best".

Answer (score 0):

If this it mySQL you can make them both [decimals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html) like you did with weight:

```
CREATE TABLE details (
  ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id int(11) NOT NULL REFERENCES user(ID),
  height FLOAT,
  weight FLOAT
);
```

You store the number in the data base, the fact that it is kg or meters or whatever is something you have to remember, or deal with after you get the data from the database.

If you want a way to remember what unit you are storing into the data base you can do this:

```
CREATE TABLE details (
  ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id int(11) NOT NULL REFERENCES user(ID),
  height_cm FLOAT,
  weight_kg FLOAT
);
```

Comment: ID seems less useful then, say, date. And you wouldn't use FLOAT for this, and you definitely wouldn't use CHAR !!